# How to get the inner elements of JsonB column in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Json like this in my JsonB column:

```
   {
    "emails": [
    {
    "email": {
    "id": "a8399412-165e-4601-824f-a55f631ad471",
    "value": "test@gmail.com"
    }
    },
    {
    "email": {
    "id": "fa09d9a7-a36a-42a4-8627-66b7554ce82e",
    "value": "test1@gmail.com"
    }
    }
    ],
"Address": [
    {
    "address": {
    "id": "a8399412-165e-4601-824f-a55f631ad471",
    "addressLine1": "Line1"
    }
    },
    {
    "address": {
    "id": "fa09d9a7-a36a-42a4-8627-66b7554ce82e",
    "addressLine2": "Line2"
    }
    }
    ],
    "lastName": {
    "id": "bc10a5a9-04ff-4a00-b167-ac3232e5cb89",
    "value": "LastName"
    },
    "firstName": {
    "id": "4ccdd400-2586-4a7f-9379-aff4d1f5d9d6",
    "value": "FirstName"
    }
    }
```

and so on. My requirement to get list of elements as key and value pairs with limit, I did a research tried different functions of postgres and I wrote the below query :

```
select response.*  from my_table t, jsonb_each_text(jsonb_column) as response;
```

If I do like this I'm getting only the root elements like emails, firstName and lastName, but I want inner elements as well along with their values like below :

```
 Key            |  value
-------           ---------
"email"     :   {"id": "a8399412-165e-4601-824f-a55f631ad471","value": "test@gmail.com"} 
"email"     :   {"id": "fa09d9a7-a36a-42a4-8627-66b7554ce82e","value": "test1@gmail.com"}
"lastName"  :   {"id": "bc10a5a9-04ff-4a00-b167-ac3232e5cb89","value": "LastName"}
"firstName" :   {"id": "4ccdd400-2586-4a7f-9379-aff4d1f5d9d6","value": "FirstName"}
 "address"  :   {"id": "a8399412-165e-4601-824f-a55f631ad471", "addressLine1": "Line1"}
 "address"  :   {"id": "a8399412-165e-4601-824f-a55f631ad471", "addressLine2": "Line2"}
```

Comment: Can you please indent the JSON to make the structure clear? Also is it really `Address` vs `address`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` function, and combine queries by `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 'email' AS key, je.* ->> 'email' AS value
  FROM my_table
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column->'emails') AS je
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'address', ja.* ->> 'address'
  FROM my_table
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column->'Address') AS ja
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'lastName', (jsonb_column->'lastName')::text 
  FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'firstName', (jsonb_column->'firstName' )::text 
  FROM my_table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c96ed2792f216c98191e97ccbed7fd7c)</kbd>

Comment: Why the `jsonb_build_array`?